# Unable to install .ipa build in some iOS devices with developer certificates using iTunes

Tags: ios

Advanced thanks to all...

actually I am creating builds for iOS devices using developer certificate. we have added nearly 28 devices, after that I added 3 more devices and modified certificates in developer account and also deleted old profiles from my Xcode organizer and added profiles using refresh button. But that build is not installing to my newly added 3 devices. but that same build is installing in all other 28 devices except newly added 3 devices.

xcode version: 4.5.2
newly added devices are: iPhone 4s(iOS 5.1.1), 5(iOS 6.0.2), 5(iOS 6.0.2).
iTunes version: 11.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You didn't obviously add the additional devices in your Ad-Hoc certificate in your Developer account.

After adding the devices, you need to add them to the certificate, re-create (update) the certificate, then download it to your Mac and import it.

Make sure to delete the old certificate, so you don't mix them up.
Also you definetely need to re-build your ipa file with the new certificate file (although it's possible to just resign the Ipa file with the new certificate, it's more easy to just rebuild it).

TestFlightApp (if you are using it) allows the re-signature of existing builds with new certificates.

Comment: If you are doing testing, TestFlight is the way to go. Makes life so much easier.